# Why doesn't this program print '4'?

Tags: c, pointers, postfix-operator

Shouldn't ptrj value be 4 after the execution of *ptrj++?

```
int j=3,*ptrj = NULL;
ptrj = &j;
*ptrj++;
printf("%i",*ptrj);
```

Comment: What does this program print instead?

Comment: it prints 0, it also says that for *ptrj++ the result is unused

Comment: And this is why `*ptr++` is bad style, no matter how common. People keep getting confused over this, the story of C for the past 40 years. Good programmers write `ptr++` on a line of its own, bad programmers write "idiomatic" goo like `*dst++ = *src++`.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes here. This is perfectly adequate to reproduce the problem, and it's NOT a simple typographical error.

Comment: @Broman you're right, it's a blatant dupe.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Hmmm, cannot argue against that. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*ptrj++` is the same as `*(ptrj++)`. What you expect is instead `(*ptrj)++`. You should look up *operator precedence* to learn more about which operators that acts before others. To understand what `ptrj++` does, you should read about *pointer arithmetic*. But here is a quick explanation:

- `*(ptrj++)` returns the value that `ptrj` points to (3), and THEN increments `ptrj` to point to the next value.
- `(*ptrj)++` returns the value that `ptrj` points to (3), and THEN increments the *value* that `ptrj` points at from 3 to 4.

This means that what you're printing is the value at address `&j + 1`, which is the value that lies right *after* the variable `j` in memory. and this is *undefined behavior*. As Sourav pointed out, you would get a warning that points you to this if you enable compiler warnings.

The only difference between `*ptrj++` and `ptrj++` is what it is returning. And since you don't use the return value, your code is equivalent to:

```
int j=3,*ptrj = NULL;
ptrj = &j;
ptrj++;
printf("%i",*ptrj);
```

Comment: OK, you were mentioning about the printf argument, I see that now.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile the program with warnings enabled, you'll see

```
source_file.c:9:5: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
     *ptrj++;
     ^
```

That means, the value computation is useless.

In other words, according to the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) `*ptrj++;` is same as `*(ptrj++);`, and as per the post-increment operator property, the value of the operation is the value of the operand, and the value is increased as the side-effect.

Quoting `C11`, chapter

> The result of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the
>   value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
>   added to it). [....]

So, this is same as

```
 *ptr;
  ptr++;
```

If you want to increment that *value* at the address, you need to enforce the operator precedence by using explicit parenthesis, like

```
(*ptrj)++;   // first get the value, then update the value.
```

Answer (score 0):

`*ptrj++` is equivalent to *(ptrj++).

desired output can be achieved using (*ptrj)++.

Please refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-operator-precedence-associativity/ to get how operator works.

Answer (score 0):

Precedence of postfix ++ is higher than *. The expression *ptrj++ is treated as *(ptrj++) as the precedence of postfix ++ is higher than *.If you want to print 4 ( ie ptrj+1 ),You should use the following code:-

```
int j=3,*ptrj = NULL;
ptrj = &j;
(*ptrj)++;
printf("%i",*ptrj);
return 0;
```

To know more about operator precedence, refer follow link:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence